# In Visual Basic, how can I see/edit tables in a remote mysql database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to build an application so that the user can see table entries in a mysql database. I'm programming this in visual basic. How can this be done?

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms application or a Website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include [MySql connector](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) to project, set a reference to `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` and create a [MySqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to remote host.

Example (C#):

```
string cstr = 
    String.Format("SERVER={0};PORT={1};UID={2};PWD={3}",
    host, port, user, password);
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(cstr);
```

VB.Net:

```
dim cstr as string = 
    String.Format("SERVER={0};PORT={1};UID={2};PWD={3}",
        host, port, user, password)
dim conn as MySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(cstr)
```

VB example *should* work...

Then you can use TableAdapters, Datasets and DataGrids to achieve your goal...